# Lifetime of access and refresh tokens

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, access-token, refresh-token

Application is intended to be used by the company for managment of intercompany documentation. These documents can contain valuable information, so it must be secure application. I am using Oauth2 with access and refresh tokens. Access token is valid for 15 minutes and refresh token is valid for 1 day. 
I have not found any recommended lifetime for tokens.

- Is 15mins for AT and 1 day for RT good? If yes, why these values are good enough OR are not good enough?
- What is optimal lifetime for AT and RT for application which must be really secure.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Gmail vs. bank accounts.

I can't tell where your business falls under. You should sit in in a meeting with your product team and explain what happens and let them decide. It's ok if it takes some try and error to get the right number.

But for Gmail the refresh token almost never expires. I can't think when was the last time I had to enter my credentials again.

For banks, the refresh token seems to be valid for only 10 minutes and if you background the bank app then you won’t be able to get a new refresh token and so you get signed out. Like my bank of America app. If I keep the app open then the app will continue to refresh the token.

And obviously refresh token expiry time should be more than your average user's session time.

Comment: so if my application is more closer to bank... which lifetime should access token have, if refresh token should be set to 10 mins?

Comment: I fount out that lifetime of refresh token should be: RT = lifetime of AT * 2; So if I choose 15mins for access token, then 30mins for refresh token is good enough?

Comment: I understand the secrecy but 10 minute refresh time to read through multiple files of documentation is bad. Think about if you go to another tab, then come and see where you scrolled down to is gone. I suppose your users will need more time than a simple bank check. I found [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/193969/how-to-decide-the-token-expiry-time-in-rest-web-service/193976) the suggestion is to make your AT double the average session duration.

Comment: The refresh token I don't think should be more than an 1-3hrs (depending or how classified the data is) for something sensitive. Think of refresh token expiry time as 'max acceptable duration user is not interacting with app, but if user comes back doesn't have to login again, because they can immediately refresh their refresh token'. To me  'RT = lifetime of AT * 2' is extremely restrictive. (some sites do AT 30min — RT 200 days). But I do realize your data is sensitive.